# Previously working activity now giving ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, kotlin

I have a simple activity that was previously working and now fails and crashes my app with the below error. I haven't changed anything related to the activity, so I'm really not sure what is going wrong here. I've looked at similar questions but nothing they've suggested has worked.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
05-15 22:13:31.381 14563-14563/com.hmadland.paranoia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.hmadland.paranoia, PID: 14563
                                                                   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.hmadland.paranoia/android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3968)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3920)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4259)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4227)
                                                                       at com.hmadland.paranoia.Profile$onCreate$2.onClick(Profile.kt:91)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

The activity is called like this

```
 Target.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, Target::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
//camera access stuff
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".Register" />
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".Login" />
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".Profile" />
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".Target" />
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".Inventory" />
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".UpcomingGames">
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>


</application>
```

Comment: can you post this method code Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)

Comment: Read this line `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)`?

Comment: You have not declared `FragmentActivity` in Manifest

Comment: Your Target class does not inherit from Activity...

Comment: Where is that `Target.setOnClickListener` called? Also, is Target really an activity? (what is its code) Why do you set click listener on `Target` if it's an activity? This looks like a mix up in using `Target` both for setting click listener and target class in an intent

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare your activity. Write this in your manifest under application tag:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:name=".FragmentActivity" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I add this in I get a bunch of build errors in the manifest

Comment: Are you referring to this because I already have it declared      
       <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".Target" />
    <activity

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by replacing

```
Target.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, Target::class.java)
              intent.putExtra("PlayerID", PlayerID)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

with this

```
Target.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, com.hmadland.paranoia.Target::class.java)
              intent.putExtra("PlayerID", PlayerID)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Not quite sure why, but might have been a naming issue with the button being called Target and activity Target.